# Another Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having trouble (again) with this DE can someone help me find the general solution for it? I feel like my biggest problem is doing the algebraic manipulations to identify what kind of DE it is.

$$y' + \frac2x y\ = y ^3/ x^3$$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a Bernoulli equation:
$$y'+P(x)y=f(x)y^n,$$
which can be solved upon using the substitution $u=y^{1-n}$.